# KDE top panel, always visible, not functioning,

Tags: kde, panel, menu-bar

Just updated the system to Kubuntu 14.04, the top panel which is set to 'always visible' is covering the windows, hiding the close, min, max buttons. It should have the top of the window fixed underneath it.